# Passing IFS values to a dynamic array

Tags: shell, scripting, scripting-language

i have a Oracle output (select output) as cand1 cand2 cand3 cand62
now i need to store these values in an array through shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
instant_client="/root/ora_client/instantclient_11_2"
output=`$instant_client/sqlplus -s HRUSER/HRUSER@TOMLWF <<EOF
set heading off
set feedback off
set lines 10000
set pagesize 10000

select count (1) from onboardingcandidates o, candidatedetails c where o.candidateid=c.candidateid and o.JOININGSTATUS='0091' and to_date(o.joiningdate)=to_date(sysdate+5);

EOF
exit

query=`$instant_client/sqlplus -s HRUSER/HRUSER@TOMLWF <<EOF
set heading off
set feedback off
set lines 10000
set pagesize 10000

select o.candidateid from onboardingcandidates o, candidatedetails c where o.candidateid=c.candidateid and o.JOININGSTATUS='0091' and to_date(o.joiningdate)=to_date(sysdate+5);
EOF
exit


i=0
echo "Throwing individual arrays:"
while [ $i -le $output ]
do
a=${query[$i]}
echo Candidate[$i]=$a
i=$(($i+1))
done
```

OUTPUT IS

```
Throwing individual arrays:

    Candidate[0]= cand1 cand2 cand3 cand62
    Candidate[1]=
    Candidate[2]=
    Candidate[3]=
    Candidate[4]=
```

REQUIRED OUTPUT

```
Throwing individual arrays:

    Candidate[0]= cand1   
    Candidate[1]= cand2
    Candidate[2]= cand3
    Candidate[3]= cand62
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `query` is a string, not an array, so `${query[$i]}` does not work as you expect.

In general, to convert a string to an array you would do this:

```
$ string="foo bar"
$ array=($string)
$ echo ${array[0]}
foo
$ echo ${array[1]}
bar
```

In your case, if you surround the `sqlplus` command with parentheses, the output will be stored in an array. Like this:

```
query=(`$instant_client/sqlplus -s HRUSER/HRUSER@TOMLWF <<EOF
set heading off
set feedback off
set lines 10000
set pagesize 10000

select o.candidateid from onboardingcandidates o, candidatedetails c where o.candidateid=c.candidateid and o.JOININGSTATUS='0091' and to_date(o.joiningdate)=to_date(sysdate+5);
EOF)
```

And then you can access elements in the `query` array using an index: `${query[$i]}`

Comment: that's helpful. Can you elaborate? Is it the same behaviour as before, different behaviour, an error? What do you see when you `echo $query`?

Comment: Yep .... its working ... thanks a ton. Actually i missed the back-quotes &  included exit function, which was throwing me a blank output. Thanks a Ton :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$ query="cand1 cand2 cand3 cand62"
$ read -a Candidate <<<$query
$ echo ${Candidate[0]}
cand1
$ echo ${Candidate[1]}
cand2
```

When you are out of your sqlplus, your "query" variable contains something like above. By simply reading the entire thing into an array as shown above, you can access the values.